# Сортировка массива json в алфавитном порядке

Tags: javascript, json, сортировка, unicode

Есть массив с данными `var alldata`. Если выводить его через

```
alert(JSON.stringify(alldata));
```

вид он иметь будет примерно такой:

> [{"ID":1,"oid":"сэм","tags":"noting"},{"ID":2,"oid":"сали","tags":"noting"},{"ID":3,"oid":"джон","tags":"noting"},{"ID":4,"oid":"лестер","tags":"noting"},{"ID":5,"oid":"кевин","tags":"noting"}]

Соответственно если выводить

```
alert(JSON.stringify(alldata[0]));
```

то будет

> {"ID":1,"oid":"сэм","tags":"noting"}

Пробую его отсортировать по значению `oid` таким образом:

```
alldata = alldata.sort(function (a,b) {
  return a.oid - b.oid;
});
```

но эффекта не дает вообще.

Что я делаю не так, как правильней?

Comment: А какого эффекта вы хотите, если вы вычитаете строки?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да просто что бы они в массиве расположились в алфавитном порядке по значению oid

Comment: Это понятно. Непонятно, на что вы рассчитываете вычитая из «сэма» «салли»…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку в `oid` содержатся символы юникода, для сортировки Вам надо использовать метод `localeCompare`

```
alldata.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.oid.localeCompare(b.oid);
})
```